# Hypothesis testing for matrices of RVs

Tags: hypothesis-testing, manova, random-matrix

I looking for the correct statistical test for comparing matrices of random variables - my IV being a categorical variable and my DVs being n by n matrices of random variables (which are themselves ordinal variables).

It looks like MANOVA might work, but is there any hypothesis test that takes into account matrix structure out there?